# Rshiny: Generating Dynamic HTML using loops

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am interested to generate a list of divs each with dynamic values in Rshiny such as below.

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
.
.
.
<div>9</div>
```

I did this by (on the server) looping through a list and vector of each element of the list. I render a UI `output$x1, output$x2, output$x3, etc`. Similarly, I loop through to create 9 UI elements on the ui function. The code is as below:

```
# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    lapply(1:9, function(i) {
      uiOutput(paste0('x', i))
    })

  )



)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  obj<- list(

    col1=1:3,
    col2=4:5,
    col3=5:9

  )

  for(elem in obj){
    for(num in elem){
      print(paste0(num))
      output[[paste0(x,num)]]<-renderUI({
        tags$div(
          tags$p(
            num
          )
        )
      })
    }
  }

}
```

shinyApp(ui, server)
I have two problems with my code:

1) Nothing is on my UI for some reason unknown to me.

2) I believe when ui is printed out, it will only print the final value of the div. For example, `output$x1 = 9,  output$x2= 9, etc`

Comment: take a look at [Shiny Modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)

Comment: @GyD not sure that helps to solve my problem but certainly an option down the line.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `tagList` in the UI, with a `do.call`
- `paste("x"`, not `paste(x`
- use `local` to define outputs in a loop, otherwise you would get only the last one

---

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    do.call(tagList, lapply(1:9, function(i) {
      uiOutput(paste0('x', i))
    }))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  obj <- list(
    col1=1:3,
    col2=4:5,
    col3=5:9
  )

  for(elem in obj){
    for(num in elem){
      local({
        mynum <- num
        output[[paste0("x",mynum)]] <- renderUI({
          tags$div(
            tags$p(
              mynum
            )
          )
        })
      })
    }
  }

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```